# How can I navigate to another view when tapping on a ZStack in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm creating an app in SwiftUI that displays a list of squares, each row containing 2 cells, each cell containing an image and text inside. What I've done is that each cell is a VStack (Image on top of Text) and then enclosed in a ZStack (to add a rectangle and make it look like a proper cell). I want to make the ZStack clickable and when tapped, navigate to another View.

This would be very easy in UIKit (that I've been working with for a while) with a CollectionView and then when each cell is selected just push a view controller to the navigation controller. However, since I have to do this project in SwiftUI, I have no clue how to do it. I've tried with NavigationViews and Navigation Links but nothing works.

The code I have for the cells is the following:

```
struct CellView: View {
    var image: String

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            VStack{
                Image(image).resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 100).scaledToFit()
                Text(image.capitalized).font(.system(size: 19, weight: Font.Weight.bold))
            }
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .stroke(Color(red: 220/255, green: 9/255, blue: 73/255), lineWidth: 5.0).frame(width: 150, height: 150)
        }
    }

    init(image: String) {
        self.image = image
    }
}

struct RowView: View {

    var image1: String
    var image2: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20.0){
            CellView(image: image1)
            CellView(image: image2)
        }
    }

    init(image1: String, image2: String) {
        self.image1 = image1
        self.image2 = image2
    }
}
```

I've tried with NavigationViews and NavigationLinks and none of it worked.

Comment: `NavigationLink` should work as long as you have a `NavigationStack` at the top the link is what you "push" and the stack is the "Controller"

Comment: Didn't get it to work, i just get this mini view inside each cell @loremipsum : https://imgur.com/a/QlTl53l

Comment: At the top, not at each cell, above everything. inUIkIt you only have 1 UINavigationController, well you only need 1 NavigationStack

Comment: But then everything becomes clickable. I want only the cells to be clickable, but with the current solution, even the white space around the cells will navigate to the new view @loremipsum

Comment: I am not a mind reader but I am assuming you are using a `List` above all this? if so that is a bad option for "Cells"

Comment: I'm not, I have a VStack with 3 elements, and each element is an HStack composed of two ZStacks. It looks like this (2nd pic): https://imgur.com/a/QlTl53l . In UIKit this is so simple to achieve (I've already done it) but I'm finding it quite hard on SwiftUI

Comment: Without a minimal reproducible example it is impossible for me to help. The navigation link is like a button make sure what you dont want to be clickable isn't included in the label

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255764/discussion-between-javier-and-lorem-ipsum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get it working is to wrap each cell as a `NavigationLink` inside a `NavigationStack`.

I don't know how your detail view is going to look, but here is a dummy implementation:

```swift
struct DetailView: View {
    let imageName: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(imageName)
    }
}
```

Inside `RowView`, wrap each `CellView` as a `NavigationLink`:

```swift
// struct RowView

var body: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20.0) {
        NavigationLink {
            DetailView(imageName: image1)
        } label: {
            CellView(image: image1)
        }
        NavigationLink {
            DetailView(imageName: image2)
        } label: {
            CellView(image: image2)
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the `NavigationStack` is in the parent view:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                RowView(image1: "cat", image2: "dog")
                RowView(image1: "horse", image2: "cow")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked!! You are the man. Thanks a lot!! Upvoting for visibility